# Warning: strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /includes/functions/general.php on line 159

Tags: php, string, parameters, warnings, strlen

I have this error:

> Warning: strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /includes/functions/general.php on line 159

in file:

```
function tep_get_all_get_params($exclude_array = '') {
    global $HTTP_GET_VARS;

    if (!is_array($exclude_array)) $exclude_array = array();

    $get_url = '';
    if (is_array($HTTP_GET_VARS) && (sizeof($HTTP_GET_VARS) > 0)) {
      reset($HTTP_GET_VARS);
      while (list($key, $value) = each($HTTP_GET_VARS)) {
        if ( (strlen($value) > 0) && ($key != tep_session_name()) && ($key != 'error') && (!in_array($key, $exclude_array)) && ($key != 'x') && ($key != 'y') ) { // THIS IS 159 LINE
          $get_url .= $key . '=' . rawurlencode(stripslashes($value)) . '&';
        }
      }
    }

    return $get_url;
  }
```

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: The error says `$value` is an array ("array given") when it should be a string ("expects parameter 1 to be string"). Why is this the case?

Comment: To prevent confusion, consider using `count` instead of `sizeof, it other programming languages `sizeof` means something completely different.

Comment: For code like this it's often advantageous to set up and IDE with debugging capabilities, then step thru any calls and iterations to understand what's going on. -- Also looks like it's written for ancient PHP4 versions, and might need a full overhaul.

Comment: So could you write to me, what should I change in code to avoid an error? I am poor php..

Comment: Stop using `$HTTP_GET_VARS` it is deprecated.  http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: If my answer didn't solve your problem, could you please post more information to allow it to be improved. Otherwise if you could accept it then it will help other users find it.

Comment: Nope @Nick still error shown: http://take.ms/V2Wvf

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your call to [`each`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.each.php). It returns an array of 4 elements:

> Elements 0 and key contain the key name of the array element, and 1 and value contain the data.

This means that `$key` gets assigned the key name, as you expect, but `$value` gets assigned an array with 3 elements with indexes `'key', 1, and 'value'`.

The simplest way to resolve this is by changing this line:

```
while (list($key, $value) = each($HTTP_GET_VARS)) {
```

to

```
foreach ($HTTP_GET_VARS as $key => $value) {
```

Note that you can remove the line:

```
reset($HTTP_GET_VARS);
```

as it is not required when using foreach. Also note that `$HTTP_GET_VARS` is deprecated as of PHP4.1.0 and you should replace it with [`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php).

Comment: It sounds like one of your GET variables must also be an array? Can you do a `var_dump($_GET)` and post that? also if you could edit your post with your current code that would be helpful.